# Powershell -replace when replacement string contains $+

Tags: powershell, replace, string-literals

I am doing a string replacement in PowerShell. I have no control over the strings that are being replaced, but I can reproduce the issue I'm having this way:

```bsh
> 'word' -replace 'word','@#$+'
@#word
```

When the actual output I need is

```bsh
> 'word' -replace 'word','@#$+'
@#$+
```

The string `$+` is being expanded to the word being replaced, and there's no way that I can find to stop this from happening. I've tried escaping the `$` with `\` (as if it was a regex), with backtick `` ` `` (as is the normal PowerShell way). For example:

```bsh
> 'word' -replace 'word',('@#$+' -replace '\$','`$')
@#`word
```

How can I replace with a literal `$+` in PowerShell? For what it's worth I'm running PowerShell Core 6, but this is reproducible on PowerShell 5 as well.

Comment: So does `'word'.Replace('word','@#$+')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the `-replace` operator, you can use the `.Replace()` method like so:

```bsh
PS> 'word'.Replace('word','@#$+')
@#$+
```

The `.Replace()` method comes from the .NET String class whereas the `-Replace` operator is implemented using `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace()`.

More info here: https://vexx32.github.io/2019/03/20/PowerShell-Replace-Operator/

Answer (score 3):

It's confusing how these codes aren't documented under "about comparison operators".  Except I have a closed bug report about them underneath if you look, 'wow, where are all these -replace 2nd argument codes documented?'.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7  That's become *my* reference.  "$+" means "Substitutes the last submatch captured".  Doubling up the dollar signs works, 'substitutes a single "$" literal':

```
'word' -replace 'word','@#$$+'

@#$+
```

Or use the scriptblock version of the second argument in PS 6 and above (may be slower):

```
'word' -replace 'word',{'@#$+'}
```

Comment: I suggest making it clear that the script-block technique has significant performance implications (won't matter in a single call, but may in a loop / when operating on a LHS array).

Comment: Turns out that the information _is_ there, just not readily discoverable, inside the `about_Regular_Expressions` topic: [Substitutions in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions#substitutions-in-regular-expressions): ; I've created [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/5416) suggesting specific improvements to the `about_Comparison_Operators` topic.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find it documented but the "Visual Basic" style escaping rule worked, repeat the character.

`'word' -replace 'word','@#$$+'` gives you: `@#$+`

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work in the way I was hoping. When I run `'word' -replace 'word',('@#$+' -replace '$','$$')` it does the same expansion when it finally runs. I can't modify the source string, so I have to do it with a `replace`

Comment: @MarkHenderson: Your replacement expression is flawed: it would have to be `('@#$+' -replace '\$','$$$$')` (sic), or, more simply, `'@#$+'.Replace('$','$$')`

Comment: Indeed, `$$` works; it is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions#substituting-a--character)

Comment: The `$$$$` version does indeed work. I've posted my contrived example so although it looks like I could use your simplified version, I don't think I can. However the `$$$$` replacement works. A line like that needs a very detailed comment I think ;)

Comment: @MarkHenderson: The comment was just a summary of what [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60068470/45375) explains in detail.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**:

***Double* the `$`** in your replacement operand to use it *verbatim*:

```
PS> 'word' -replace 'word', '@#$$+' # note the doubled '$'
@#$+
```

---

PowerShell's [`-replace` *operator*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375):

- uses a ***regex*** ([regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)) as the ***search* (1st) operand**.

  - If you want t**o use a search string *verbatim***, you must ***escape* it**:

    - programmatically: with **`[regex]::Escape()`**
    - or, **in string *literals***, you can **alternatively `\`-escape *individual characters*** that would otherwise be interpreted as regex metacharacters.
- uses a **non-literal string that *can refer to what the regex matched*** as the  ***replacement* (2nd) operand**, via `$`-prefixed tokens such as `$&` or `$+` (see link above or [Substitutions in Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions#substitutions-in-regular-expressions)).

  - To **use a replacement string *verbatim***, ***double* any `$` chars.** in it, which is *programmatically* most easily done with **`.Replace('$', '$$')`** (see below).

---

**If *both* your search string *and* your replacement string are to be used *verbatim*, consider using the `[string]` type's [`.Replace()` *method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) instead, as shown in [Brandon Olin's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067201/45375).**

- Caveat: **`.Replace()` is case-*sensitive* by default, whereas `-replace` is case-*insensitive*** (as PowerShell *generally* is); use a different `.Replace()` overload for case-insensitivity, or, conversely, use the `-creplace` variant in PowerShell to get case-sensitivity.

  - *[PowerShell (Core) 7+ only]* Case-*insensitive* `.Replace()` example:
    `'FOO'.Replace('o', '@', 'CurrentCultureIgnoreCase')`
- **`.Replace()` only accepts a *single* string** as input, whereas **`-replace` accepts an *array* of strings** as the LHS; e.g.:

  - `'hi', 'ho' -replace 'h', 'f' # -> 'fi', 'fo'`
- `.Replace()` is faster than `-replace`, though that will only matter in loops with high iteration counts.

---

**If you were to stick with the `-replace` operator** in your case:

As stated, ***doubling* the `$` in your replacement operand** ensures that they're treated *verbatim* in the replacement:

```
PS> 'word' -replace 'word', '@#$$+' # note the doubled '$$'
@#$+
```

To do this simple escaping *programmatically*, you can leverage the `.Replace()` method:

```
'word' -replace 'word', '@#$+'.Replace('$', '$$')
```

You could also do it with a *nested* `-replace` operation, but that gets unwieldy (`\$` escapes a `$` in the regex; `$$` represent a *single* `$` in the replacement string):

```
# Same as above.
'word' -replace 'word', ('@#$+' -replace '\$', '$$$$')
```

---

To put it differently: The equivalent of:

```
'word'.Replace('word', '@#$+')
```

is (note the use of the case-*sensitive* variant of the `-replace` operator, `-creplace`):

```
'word' -creplace [regex]::Escape('word'), '@#$+'.Replace('$', '$$')
```

However, as stated, if both the search string and the replacement operand are to be used verbatim, using `.Replace()` is preferable, both for concision and performance.