# Regex-based string replacement operation not working

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, escaping

I have a file exp.txt with below content

```
 hi. what are you doing. are you fine?
```

This is my code:

```
$a = "are you fine?"

for($i=0;$i -lt $ar.Length; $i++)
{
    (Get-Content "exp.txt") -replace $ar[$i], "$&~" | Set-Content "exp.txt"
}
```

I want to append `~` at the end of whatever text i put in $ar variable. But the above code does not work if i type "are you fine?" in `$ar` variable. Symbols like "*" "$" "+" also dont work. i need help

Comment: Where is `$ar` defined? I can see `$a` defined, not `$ar`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to treat a search expression passed to the regex-based [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) as a *literal* string, **you must *escape* regex metacharacters such as `?`**, which you can do ***programmatically* by calling [`[regex]::Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape)** (in a ***literal* regex string**, you could manually escape indiv. chars. with **`\`**):

```
(Get-Content exp.txt) -replace [regex]::Escape($ar[$i]), '$&~'
```

<sup>Note how I've used `'...'` (*single*-quoting) for the replacement operand, which is preferable so as to avoid confusion with the string expansion that PowerShell itself performs up front in `"..."` (*double*-quoted) strings. Similarly, `'...'` is preferable for a literal search regex.</sup>

Sticking with the regex-based **`-replace`** operator **in your case makes sense** for two reasons:

- You want to (directly and succinctly) **refer to *whatever was matched* by the regex in the replacement expression**, via placeholder `$&`.
- You want to **perform replacements on an *array* of input strings in a *single* operation** (like many PowerShell operators, `-replace` supports an *array* of strings as its LHS, and then operates *on each element*).

By contrast, in cases where ***literal* string substitutions with a *single* input string** is needed, use of the **`[string]` type's  [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) method** is the **simpler and faster** option, but note that it is **case-*sensitive* by default** (unlike `-replace`).
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60068470/45375) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The `-replace` uses regular expressions, so special characters are interpreted.  Looks like you don't want that, so try using

```
(Get-Content "exp.txt").Replace("something", "something else")
```

I'm not clear on exactly what you want in the end, but this should get you past the problem with special characters.