# Can I replace a line containing parenthesis and quotation marks with -replace in powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

I have the below powershell file and need to replace multiple commands. Is it possible to replace the text containing parenthesis and quotation marks with the -replace command?

```
 $original_file = 'D:\Prtr\tr.lst'
 $destination_file =  'D:\Prtr\pr.iso'
 (gc $original_file -raw) | ForEach-Object {
 $_ -replace 'TL_FORCE(11,"PRX",0,100)', '$(FREE_LQQ)(1,2)' `
 -replace 'TL_FORCE(11,"PRX",0,200)', '$(FREE_LQQ)(2,2)' `
 -replace 'TL_FORCE(11,"PRX",0,200)', '$(FREE_LQQ)(3,2)' `
 } | Set-Content $destination_file
```

The way I have it currently written doesn't replace anything. I tried using a double backslash to isolate the quotation marks but without success.

Comment: There's not enough information in this question to help you.  Please provide a sample of your source file.

Comment: I mean on the face of it you just escape parenthesis ( eg. `\(` and `\)` ) to match them, the double quotes `"` would be replaced just by using them since you are using single quotes `'` to define your regex here.  Simple as that.  So if the literal text you are looking to match is `TL_FORCE(11,"PRX",0,200)` you would just use this instead: `TL_FORCE\(11,"PRX",0,200\)` as your match

Comment: Thank you Ben! This answers the question...just using a backslash TL_FORCE\(11,"PRX",0,200\).           I didn't understand that the double quotes are already being taken care of by '.

Comment: The alternative to character-individual escaping with `\ ` is to use the `[regex]::Escape()` method or to use the `.Replace()` method of string objects, which performs _literal_ substring searches and replacements, albeit case-_sensitively_ by default). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60068470/45375) to the linked post.